# After some time, some IPs stop being reachable through Linksys router WRT3200ACM

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Linsys WRT3200ACM router. Firmware is up to date and I have not made any fancy settings, beside configuring the WiFi password and name.

After some time, some external IPs stop being reachable. I also noticed that they appear to be the same. Most notabily ubuntu.lagis.at, the Austrian ubuntu update server, is always among them.

The router is behind an ISP modem/router. Another router behind the ISP router works fine. It is also possible to ping the ip that does not work thorugh the routers webinterface. Only on wifi it does not work. After reboot it works for a while. The router is not very busy...

Does anyone have an idea what might be happening?

Comment: When this problems happens is the dns service on the router running?

Comment: 1) You're saying "IP not reachable" but "ping to IP works". What do you mean by IP? IP address or DNS name? Or one time this, the other time that? 2) You say that the IP can be reached from the router's GUI but not via WiFi and conclude that the problem is related to "only WiFi". Did you try LAN, and what is the result? 3) What are the DNS configurations of the Linksys and the computer you use? 4) What does "stop being reachable" really mean -- which service do you refer to, what do you observe, which messages do you get?